# How to reboot device without using su (Superuser)?

Tags: android, adb, android-reboot

I want reboot the device. i am able to do with root.using 
below code.

```
  public static void rebootDevice()
    {
        try
        {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
            os.writeBytes("reboot \n");
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {

            t.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

but boss told me try without using **su** . how to do that any help?

Comment: There are API's for this, but they only work in special cases. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager#reboot(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately its not possible if you neither have root permission nor your app is system app. **If your app is a System app** then you can do following:

**In your Manifest file put following permission:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT"/>
```

**Use following code to restart:**

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
pm.reboot(null);
```

Comment: getting      Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10092 nor current process has android.permission.REBOOT. app crashing

Comment: As I said, it will only work if your app is system app

Comment: why rebooting in normal app consider as security flaw any idea?

Comment: Well, not all apps have good intentions like yours. They can make device enter in an endless Reboot loop thus making the device useless.